# fs.appendFile but fail if path does *not* exist

Tags: node.js, fs

Looking through the fs docs, I am looking for a flag that I can use with fs.appendFile, where an error will be raised if the path does *not* exist.

I am seeing flags that pertain to raising errors if the path does already exist, but I am not seeing flags that will raise errors if the path does *not* exist -

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I assume you mean `fs.appendFile()`, since the `fs.append()` you refer to is not in the `fs` module.

There does not appear to be a flag that opens the file for appending that returns an error if the file does not exist.  You could write one yourself.  Here's a general idea for how to do so:

```
fs.appendToFileIfExist = function(file, data, encoding, callback) {
    // check for optional encoding argument
    if (typeof encoding === "function") {
        callback = encoding;
        encoding = 'utf8';
    }
    // r+ opens file for reading and writing. Error occurs if the file does 
    fs.open(file, 'r+', function(err, fd) {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        function done(err) {
            fs.close(fd, function(close_err) {
                fd = null;
                if (!err && close_err) {
                    // if no error passed in and there was a close error, return that
                    return callback(close_err);
                } else {
                    // otherwise return error passed in
                    callback(err);
                }
            });
        }

        // file is open here, call done(err) when we're done to clean up open file

        // get length of file so we know how to append
        fs.fstat(fd, function(err, stats) {
            if (err) return done(err);

            // write data to the end of the file
            fs.write(fd, data, stats.size, encoding, function(err) {
                done(err);
            });

        });
    });
}
```

You could, of course, just test to see if the file exists before calling `fs.appendFile()`, but that is not recommended because of race conditions.  Instead, it is recommended that you set the right flags on `fs.open()` and let that trigger an error if the file does not exist.

Comment: Thanks yes I meant fs.appendFile, I edited the original question